# How to display data form http request in alert in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to display a data from http request and display it in alert but all I get is [object object]  and in my console, I can see my data  [{code: "MNV"}] but I don't know how I can make display in the alters

```
  Coupons(offer,code){
this.peopleservice.getCoupons(offer,code).subscribe(data=>this.Code=data);

       let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({

             title: 'code',
             message:this.Code,

             buttons:[
                 {
                    text: 'Cancel',
      handler: data => {

        console.log(this.Code)

                 }
                 }
             ]
        }

        );
        prompt.present();
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're saying you wanna display MNV in your alert?

If yes, you need to do this

```
let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({

         title: 'code',
         message: this.Code.code,

         buttons:[
             {
                text: 'Cancel',
  handler: data => {

    console.log(this.Code)

             }
             }
         ]
    }

    );
    prompt.present();
```

Comment: it did not work with me I got ./alertCmp class alertCmp caused by undefined is not objected (evaluating this.Code.code)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create and present your alert inside the function passed to the subcribe, because it's a stream and if you call this service (getCoupons) and do not wait this to have a return and create your alert, you don't have the values yet.

```
Coupons(offer,code){
  this.peopleservice.getCoupons(offer,code)
  .subscribe( data => {

        let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'code',
            message: data.message, //or anything else
            buttons:[
                {
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    handler: data => {

                    }
                }
            ]
        });
        prompt.present();

    });
}
```

Comment: I try doing what you said data.code but my alert is empty and I try to log to see what in it and I get undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
    Coupons(offer,code,Store){


  this.peopleservice.getCoupons(offer,code,Store)
  .subscribe(data =>{this.Coode = data[0].code

    let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'code',
            message: this.Code, 
            buttons:[
                {
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    handler: data => {

                    }
                }
            ]
        })
        prompt.present();


},resError=>this.dataError(2));

}
```